# How to select multiple files with <input type="file">?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

How to select multiple files with `<input type="file">`?

Comment: It's about javascript and html

Comment: Do you mean upload multiple files in one go (when you select one at a time and then click upload)? Or do you mean using ctrl+click to select several files in one browser window?

Comment: You can do it with HTML5 using the multiple attribute on the input element. <input type='file' multiple=''> Here's a great fiddle that utilizes it: http://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/Yvgc2/

Answer (score 240, accepted):

New answer:

In HTML5 you can add the `multiple` attribute to select more than 1 file.

```
<input type="file" name="filefield" multiple="multiple">
```

---

Old answer:

> You can only select 1 file per `<input type="file" />`. If you want to
>   send multiple files you will have to use multiple input tags or use
>   Flash or Silverlight.

Comment: Gmail uses Flash to do this

Comment: @Costa On the 20th of October of 2009 most browsers didn't support that feature and Niavlys already showed the html5 solution 2 years ago.

Comment: this answer is more ancient than the dinosaurs

Comment: The HTML5 multiple attribute is supported on current versions of all major browsers. See: http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple (N.B. if you're managing support for older browsers, continue to be aware of their support too)

Comment: this multiple="multiple" is not user friendly, the avarage user doesn't understand it, doesn't even know what a "ctrl button" does, and it cannot select files in different folders.

Comment: if this is form is being submitted to a php form name should be `name="filefield[]"` so that it returns an array

Comment: @Jean-Paul This solution is *especially* user-friendly, because it can *also* be used to add files one at a time (if a user doesn't know how to select multiple files). Allowing to use the field multiple times, if necessary, is your job while implementing the form.

Comment: As a side not, selected files info can be accessed via `files` property on the input element.

Answer (score 100):

There is also HTML5 `<input type="file" multiple name="files[]" />` ([specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-multiple)).

Browser support is quite good on desktop (just not supported by IE 9 and prior), less good on mobile, I guess because it's harder to implement correctly depending on the platform and version.

Comment: Not supported on IE9 and prior :(

Answer (score 34):

The whole thing should look like:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' action='submitFormTo.php'> 
    <input type='file' name='files[]' multiple>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Make sure you have the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute in your `<form>` tag, or you can't read the files on the server side after submission!

Comment: unless you submit it with a websocket or ajax

Answer (score 18):

This jQuery plugin ([jQuery File Upload Demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)) does it without flash, in the form it's using:

```
<input type='file' name='files[]' multiple />
```

Comment: also not supported on IE9-, https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support#multiple-file-selection

Answer (score 16):

You can do it now with HTML5

In essence you use the multiple attribute on the file input.

```
<input type='file' multiple>
```

Comment: What about support for this thing? Canisuse.com doesn't have the info.

Comment: I'm not sure, I checked the same place, haha.

Comment: [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) doesn't have `.name` property, so title in your example is always `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/m5jeyeyt/1/

Comment: @HubertOG https://caniuse.com/input-file-multiple

Answer (score 3):

Thats easy ...

```
<input type='file' multiple>
$('#file').on('change',function(){
     _readFileDataUrl(this,function(err,files){
           if(err){return}
           console.log(files)//contains base64 encoded string array holding the 
           image data 
     });
});
var _readFileDataUrl=function(input,callback){
    var len=input.files.length,_files=[],res=[];
    var readFile=function(filePos){
        if(!filePos){
            callback(false,res);
        }else{
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onload=function(e){              
                res.push(e.target.result);
                readFile(_files.shift());
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(filePos);
        }
    };
    for(var x=0;x<len;x++){
        _files.push(input.files[x]);
    }
    readFile(_files.shift());
};
```

Comment: This is already answered clearly. What is the need to add a javascript example?

Comment: cause its nice ?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `multiple` attribute

```
<input type='file' multiple>
```

Read more about [multiple attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_multiple.asp)

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has provided new attribute multiple for input element whose type attribute is file.
So you can select multiple files and IE9 and previous versions does not support this.

NOTE: be carefull with the name of the input element.
when you want to upload multiple file you should use array and not string as the value of the 
name attribute.

ex: input type="file" name="myPhotos[]" multiple="multiple"

and if you are using php then you will get the data in $_FILES and 
use var_dump($_FILES) and see output and do processing
Now you can iterate over and do the rest

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has provided new attribute multiple for input element whose type attribute is file. So you can select multiple files and IE9 and previous versions does not support this.

NOTE: be carefull with the name of the input element. when you want to upload multiple file you should use array and not string as the value of the name attribute.

ex:

```
input type="file" name="myPhotos[]" multiple="multiple"
```

and if you are using php then you will get the data in $_FILES and use var_dump($_FILES) and see output and do processing Now you can iterate over and do the rest

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" multiple name="img[]"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
print_r($_FILES['img']['name']);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Copy and paste this into your html:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

// files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
var output = [];
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
              f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
              f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
              '</li>');
}
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}
```

This comes to you, through me, from this webpage: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/