# Fetching multiple image in Phonegap FileTransfer

Tags: php, android, cordova

I am sending multiple images to server using Phonegap FileTransfer.
Images are getting successfully delivered on server side as I get it in logcat.

Now I don't know how to fetch images on sever side?
I tried following code:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);

//$new_image_name = "namethisimag1.jpg";

$new_image_name = array("red.jpg", "green.jpg", "blue.jpg"); 
foreach ($new_image_name as $key => $item) {

$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/AppData/uploads/".$item;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
} 
?>
```

Only 1 image red.jpg is getting uploaded. Help me with foreach loop.

on Every file transfer this page is called on server side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [uploading multiple image files to php mysql gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603685/uploading-multiple-image-files-to-php-mysql-gallery)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using POST method in some sort of form..

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) is a 3 dimensional array when uploading multiple files

This should fix it:

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key]);