# how can I fill image data from database into value of multiple input?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to insert my images data from database into value of multiple input , But I don't have any idea how to do it . because I do not know how data store in multiple inputs

I want to build an edit page and I have to bring those images for user .

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,">
```

Comment: give every upload ine id and add for every file the link to file, so you have 10 Files and 10 rows, the id, you can use to reference the upload

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: there are multiiple tutorials see if this helos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603685/uploading-multiple-image-files-to-php-mysql-gallery