# how to get Uploaded multiple files using multiple attribute in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

provide some sample code to upload multiple files in spring framework.

when i search solution for this everyone wrote jsp page like this :

```
<input type='file' name='files[]' multiple />
```

but this was not the scenario what i am really want

Here my jsp page code : **multiFileSelect.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input name="files" type="file" multiple/>
            <button type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me...

Comment: There are many resources out there that you can find if you search well. `So show SO your attempt` and then people here can help you. still your question is less detailed one. so giving an answer or code for this, will be highly unlikely by another SO user.

Answer (score 0):

I think Chann has given the solution to your question.

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

for more general one

```
<input type="file" multiple/>
```

Since you have asked an example usage of that, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593225/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-input-type-file) SO question (I don't know why you missed this) and the sample [code example](http://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/Yvgc2/) by SO user [Costa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1027004/costa).