# How to upload and insert multiple images in PHP?

Tags: php, css, html, cakephp

I am new to php and i want solution for multiple images upload into php server.

I am using this way to multiple upload images file but getting issue when i multiple upload images.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" />
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload File" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add_more').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file' />");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Upload your server side code and please explain what kind of error you are getting.

Comment: error is image not upload

Comment: Then post the error you are getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select multiple files with <input type="file">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593225/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-input-type-file)

Comment: Please post the full code with the detailed issue you are facing as you posted add more jquery code but where is add_more in the code we don't know so please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

please add multiple attribute in input

```
<input name="file" type="file" multiple />
```