# Something is wrong with to select multiple photos, How can I solve

Tags: html

Error is Attribute name "multiple" associated with an element type "input" must be followed by the '=' character.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/addPackage" method="POST" enctype="myltipart/form-data">
    <div class="horizontal-divider m-0 m-b-15"></div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" multiple>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What software are you using that's giving you the error? Chrome? Firefox? Have you tried `<input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" multiple>` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1593259/1377706) (on a different question) seems to indicate?

Comment: I use firefox .