# ERROR in ./node_modules/ng4-files/index.ts is not part of the compilation output

Tags: angular5, ng-file-upload

I Started using Angular5 few days ago

Recently I got an error that -

*

> ./node_modules/ng4-files/index.ts is not part of the
>   compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.

*

same issue is mentioned here also - https://github.com/bonjurmrfirst/ng4-files/issues/17

Problem is that .TS file is not compiled into output and I didn't found any script for compiling ts file into output.

**Solution worked for me is**

Add that index.ts file to tsconfig.json's "include" block. See below example:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "node_modules/ng4-files/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: try this its work for me,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-5-file-upload