# How to post images to NodeJS server form Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, multer

I have a NodeJS rest-API that accepts images and content like text in the same function.

I'm using multer in my NodeJS server to handle the images, more precisely I have the same example from below just I have content with it also.

```
var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }])
app.post('/cool-profile', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is an object (String -> Array) where fieldname is the key, and the value is array of files
  //
  // e.g.
  //  req.files['avatar'][0] -> File
  //  req.files['gallery'] -> Array
  //
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```

How can I send the images form Angular 4 frontend page to NodeJS backend.

Thank you!

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-5-file-upload/47938117#47938117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send images files via formdata :

```
let myForm = new FormData();
myForm.append('avatar',  image);
```