# Angular 5: How to upload an image

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5.
I have an requirement where I need to upload an image on a page and display the image?

Is there any Angular 5 tag or html tag I can do this?

I am attaching a screen shot what it look like. The user click "upload" button and there should be a pop-up where the user choose the file to upload. After they choose the file to upload and click open button. The image will appear on page?

[image]

Any hint or suggestion will be greatly appreciated it!!

Comment: Have you checked `<input type="file">` ?

There are many Angular libraries for processing file uploads and such, a quick Google search may be helpful.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload

Answer (score 8):

You can use the tag from HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" />
```

and in the component:

```
public files: any[];

contructor() { this.files = []; }

onFileChanged(event: any) {
  this.files = event.target.files;
}

onUpload() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (const file of this.files) {
      formData.append(name, file, file.name);
  }
  this.http.post('url', formData).subscribe(x => ....);
}
```

The formData will hold the stream to your upload.

P.S. you can mark the HTML with the attribute: "multiple" and you can upload multiple data if your server can handle it.