# Image uploading in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, google-cloud-storage

I was trying to upload an image using Angular to a google storage bucket. And everything is working fine with Postman.
But I'm stuck with angular typescript.  Can anyone suggest to me a way to do this?

**.html file**

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" class="form-control upload-btn" formControlName="imageUpload" placeholder="Upload Images" (change)="uploadImage($event)"  required>
```

**.ts file**

```
 uploadImage(event: any) {
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
  const uploadImage=event.target.files[0];

  const fileObject = {
    userId: this.userId,
    bucketName: 'Test123',
    image: uploadImage
  };

  this.userService.uploadImage(fileObject).subscribe(data=>{
  },err=>{
    console.log("error occured")
  }
  )
}
```

}

**.service file**

```
uploadImage(fileObject: any){
return this.http.post('http://localhost:1337' + 'upload-image' , fileObject);
```

}

No any error occurs on the backend side. It worked fine with *Postman*.
Im not sure about the **.ts** file.

Comment: What's the error you are seeing in frontend/browser or developer tools

Comment: can you share the which url you are using in the postman to upload can you post here the url

Comment: Hi @chintuyadavsara, error is it will never go inside this.userService.uploadImage(fileObject).subscribe(data=>{
  } this one. Therefore image didn't add the bucket

Comment: Hi @ManektechKnowledgeBase, I used `http://localhost:1337/upload-image` this url which is same as in the service file.

Comment: if it is not going inside, it might go to error, please check what the error is and please give detailed information

Comment: @chintuyadavsara please check this.        error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: 'Uploaded the file successfully'}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:1337/upload-image"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:1337/upload-image"

Comment: @HariDev Please open chrome dev tools and go to network tab and see the response once, this error usually occurs when the server returns an error (e.g. a 500 server error)

Comment: can you share the pay load for both postman and payload from network tab screen shot

Comment: `uploadImage(fileObject: any){
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + GlobalConstants.uploadImage  , fileObject, { responseType: 'text'});
  }` when I use `{ responseType: 'text'}` , it went inside the service @chintuyadavsara. But still not shown in the bucket

Comment: Hey, Try using FormData to upload any image to a server.

Comment: @PrasenjeetSymon can you explain how to do that ?

Comment: Here is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343853/angular-5-how-to-upload-an-image) which shows how to use FormData as suggested by @PrasenjeetSymon

Comment: Thanks guys! I could do with using FormData. Thanks for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @PrasenjeetSymon using FormData will help to upload images in Angular.

Here is the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343853/angular-5-how-to-upload-an-image) which demonstrate how to use FormData

> You can use the tag from HTML:
>
> ```
> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" />
> ```
>
> and in the component:
>
> ```
> public files: any[];
>
> contructor() { this.files = []; }
>
> onFileChanged(event: any) {
>   this.files = event.target.files;
> }
>
> onUpload() {
>   const formData = new FormData();
>   for (const file of this.files) {
>       formData.append(name, file, file.name);
>   }
>   this.http.post('url', formData).subscribe(x => ....);
> }
> ```