# Upload image to Web Api 2 Using angular 5

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, form-data

I have looked at several SO question and answer but not able to solve my problem. My code is like below:

**HTML**

```
 <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="File" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
 <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="uploadFileToActivity()">Upload</button>
```

**Component**

```
  handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
  }

  uploadFileToActivity() {

    this._dishAddService.postFile(this.fileToUpload).subscribe(data => {

      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

**Service**

```
 postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });    
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'post' });
    return this.http.post(this.httpRequestUrl + 'api/dish/UploadDishImage', formData, options)
      .map(
        (response => response.json()))
      .catch(CommonFunctionService.handleError);
  }
```

**API**

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("UploadDishImage")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadJsonFile()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/" + postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

When request hit the API, files count is 0. I have spent whole two days to figure out what is going wrong but also not able to figure out wrong. I don't think there is wrong with the code because for some other it is working. I took code from different SO accepted answer. Could anybody help me figure out what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-5-file-upload/47938117#47938117

Comment: @GregorDoroschenko  I have already looked at it and main code in above question is the answer you referred.

Comment: Oh ok :-) Try to remove ``'Content-Type': 'application/json'`` from your headers settings, because you post request is FormData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileUpload is super easy with angular. You can either use this description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-5-file-upload/47938117#47938117)  or follow my steps.

In your component template just attach a change event to your input and let it call a function which handles the files to upload. *$event.target.files* includes your files.

```
<input type="file" (change)="upload($event.target.files)">
```

in your components class you need to import your **files.service.ts** (or what ever you called it) and provide it either in your regarding module or in the component itself if you don't want to reuse it.

```js
import { FilesService } from 'PATHTO/files.service';
[...]
contructor(private filesService: FilesService) { }
```

Then you can implement the following function in your component class for a single file upload, otherwise cycle through files.item and attach it to formData

```js
upload(files: FileList) {
  const file = files.item(0);

  this.filesService.upload(file).subscribe(
    res => /* Place your success actions here */,
    error => /* Place your error actions here */
  );
}
```

Make sure you have defined an url attribute in your environment or replace the post url with a static one. The **files.service.ts** for example can look like this

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { environment } from 'PATHTO/environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class FilesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  upload(file: File): Observable<Object> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', file, file.name);

    return this.http.post(`${environment.url}avatar.php`, formData);
  }
}
```

For example on php server side you are then able to catch those files with **$_FILES** variable. Don't know very much about Asp.net but I think there has to be an equivalence.

Hope this helps, have a nice day! Cheers.

Comment: Hey  thanks man. From your code i can see what i was missing. I should have use HttpClient directive not HttpPost

Answer (score 3):

This way I implement upload image to web API in project.

I share for whom concern.

```
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Image', image, image.name);
    formData.append('ComponentId', componentId);
    return this.http.post('/api/dashboard/UploadImage', formData);
```

Step by step

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/dashboard/UploadImage")]
public HttpResponseMessage UploadImage()
        {
            string imageName = null;
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            //Upload Image
            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files["Image"];
            //Create custom filename
            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                imageName = new String(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(" ", "-");
                imageName = imageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + imageName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
}
```

HTML form

```
<form #imageForm=ngForm (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(Image)">

                    <img [src]="imageUrl" class="imgArea">
                    <div class="image-upload">
                        <label for="file-input">
                            <img src="upload.jpg" />
                        </label>

                        <input id="file-input" #Image type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"/>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-large btn-submit" [disabled]="Image.value=='' || !imageForm.valid"><i class="material-icons">save</i></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

TS file to use API

```
OnSubmit(Image) {
    this.dashboardService.uploadImage(this.componentId, this.fileToUpload).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('done');
        Image.value = null;
        this.imageUrl = "/assets/img/logo.png";
      }
    );
  }
```

Service TS

```
uploadImage(componentId, image) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Image', image, image.name);
        formData.append('ComponentId', componentId);
        return this.http.post('/api/dashboard/UploadImage', formData);
    }
```