# Html input type file

Tags: html, angular, form-data, angular-file-upload

I'm working on an application, I have to upload more than 4k files with Angular 5 and Html, I'm using input type file but after I select all files I can't see the files and if I check the event target I can see the length of the list is 0.
So is it a limitation from Html and input ?
And their is a solution to avoid this problem ?
Best regards
Quentin

Comment: post your angular code here with html

Comment: Have you added the attribute multiple? `<input type="file" multiple>`

Answer (score 1):

In Angular applications you should use `(change)`-event on your file input-tag. In this change-event you should call an function, which handles the event value. Give to this function your files. Here is an example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file"
           id="file"
           (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" multiple>
</div>
```

In your component.ts file you should create `handleFileInput` function. In this function you can manage selected files. Define an global variable for single (of type `File`) or for multiple files (of array type `File[]`). Here is an example:

```
singleFileToUpload: File = null;
multipleFilesToUpload: File[] = [];

handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.singleFileToUpload = files.item(0);
    this.multipleFilesToUpload = files;
}
```

After that you can upload a single file or iterate multiple files and upload that. Beware: use `FormData` to uplaod file to API via POST.

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-5-file-upload/47938117#47938117), which have good explanation about file upload in angular.

Comment: hello there, when I use `$event.target.files` as an argument, it fails to compile. I came here from your other post, and everything works well except for this part, what could possibly be wrong here? I am using Angular 12 , thanks for your attention