# Angular 5: Upload file to Node.js with Multer

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, multer

I have the following code in my service:

```
uploadFiles( files ) {
    let fd = new FormData();
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    fd.append( 'file', files[0], files[0].name );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( xhr.readyState === 4 ) {
          if( xhr.status === 200 ) {
            console.log('file uploaded');
            resolve(xhr.response );
          } else {
            console.log('Fail');
            reject( xhr.response );
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.open('POST', `${this.url}/equipos/uploadfiles`);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhr.send(fd);
    });
  }
```

When I send to the backend (in Node) I get the following error in the `console.log( req );` object:

[image]

When I remove the line `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` I get an error with Multer but I do not know how to debugge:

[image]

Multer works well when I use it with Postman, but not with my application in Angular.

I have also reviewed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-5-file-upload) but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error and I share it with the community. In my routes I had:

```
api.post('/equipos/uploadfiles', upload.array('arch', 12), equipoController.uploadFiles);
```

I was using `archi` instead of `file`. Change that line for this and it worked:

```
api.post('/equipos/uploadfiles', upload.array('file', 12), equipoController.uploadFiles);
```