# Angular 6 file uploading

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

Been stuck on this for a while now.  I have a mean stack application using angular 6.  I'm trying to upload save a file to my backend.  I've found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-5-file-upload) article.  But either I receive an error a crypt something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Error</title> </head> <body> <pre>Error: ENOENT: no such file or 
 directory, open ''<br> at 
 Error (native)</pre> </body> </html>
```

returned from the server or the req.file is empty and my save doesnt happen.  I'm trying to piece together the best way to do this.

Thanks

here is my end point

```
app.post('/api/posts', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {

const post = new Post({
  title: req.body.title,
  content: req.body.content,
  image:req.file
});    

post
.save()
.then(createdPost => {
  res.status(201).json({
    status: true,
    id: createdPost._id,
  });
})
.catch(error => {
  res.status(500).json({ status: false, message: 'Didnt save ', error });
});
```

});

And here is how I set up multer, grid file stream and storage

```
    let gfs;
conn.once('open', () => {
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});


const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: connection,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with multer trying to create directory
Write the proper pathname (probably ./uploads/) . and make sure that folder is writable