# Angular 6 formdata

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6.I am sending image file data through form data.But I am enable to get file data in API.here is my code

```
 UpdateLogoprofile(data: any): Observable<any> {
    debugger;
    const model = {};
    const url = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'Client/UploadFileToStorage';
    console.log(data);
   // const body = JSON.stringify(data);
   //const body = data;
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'bearer ' + this.auth_token + ''
           })
         };
    return this.http.post(url, data, httpOptions)
        // .map(this.extractData)
        .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

and FormData

```
 let formData: FormData = new FormData();
                     formData.append(file.name,file);
                    // formData.append('StudentId',this.StudentID);
                    debugger;
                    this._ClientService.UpdateLogoprofile(data).subscribe(
                        image => {
```

**The Problem:**
I am not able to acces `formData` in API

Comment: Are you seeing your image data in the request that is being sent to your API ?

Comment: You might want to refer to this one :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload

Comment: Problem is not able to acces formdata in API

Comment: I changed and checked but no lucky

Comment: Content type should be `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'` as when your form includes any <input type="file"> element you should use multipart/form-data and change `this._ClientService.UpdateLogoprofile(data)` to `this._ClientService.UpdateLogoprofile(formData)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the file append line with

```
formData.append('key', file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this line

```
this._ClientService.UpdateLogoprofile(data)
```

to

```
this._ClientService.UpdateLogoprofile(formData);
```

Also in header content type should be 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'