# Typescript file upload validation

Tags: angular, html, typescript, file-upload, angular6

I'm trying to upload a file but i get an error for the following code. The error is **property does not exist on type HTML Element**. How to resolve this?

I have commented the error for the following line of code.

> **component.html**

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();"/>

   <ul>
     <label>Select a Module Name</label>
     <select id = "ModuleDropDown">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="Recuirtmnet">Recuirtmnet</option>
       <option value="Talent" selected="selected">Talent</option>
       <option value="Attrition">Attrition</option>
       <option value="Performance">Performance</option>
       <option value="Survey">Survey</option>
      </select>
     </ul>

    <div id="fileName"></div>
    <div id="fileSize"></div>
    <div id="fileType"></div>
```

> **component.ts**

```
fileSelected() {

    //Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
    let file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]; 

    if (file) {
        let fileSize = 0;
        if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
            this.fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
        else
            this.fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

        document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
        document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
        document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
        let dropDown = document.getElementById("ModuleDropDown");


        //Property 'options' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
        //Property 'selectedIndex' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
        let dpVal = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;

        let init_params = {};
        this.init_params.action = 'prepare';
        this.init_params.file_name = file.name;
        this.init_params.file_size = fileSize;
        this.init_params.moduleName = dpVal;

        ws.send(JSON.stringify(init_params))
        console.log("sending init params.....")

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to upload a file and after submitting  trying to get the file name, file size and file type and in the other part trying to get the dropdown value.

Comment: I think you use a bad approach. In angular batter use change event and handle this event. And then get the file from event There you can find a good example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code. You're using Vanilla JavaScript instead of leveraging the Angular Syntax.

1. The change on the File Input can be tracked using `(change)` and passing an `$event` Object to the Change Handler.
2. You can use `[(ngModel)]` to get the value of the selected option from the dropdown.
3. It's not advisable to use `document` to access the DOM and make changes to it or show data to it. You should use the String Interpolation Syntax(`{{}}`) instead.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgckkf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Select an Option and then Upload a File to see the Selected File Details on the UI and the Selected Dropdown Option on the console.