# Appending data to FormData in angular

Tags: angular, file-upload, form-data

I have a file that i wants to append it properties to formData before sending it to the server for upload but can't seem to appending. here is the code

```
uploadFile() {
let data = new FormData();
data.append('image', this.file, this.file.name);
console.log(data);
}
```

am getting an empty object in the console even though the file variable has the file data. is the anything am missing?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload/47938117#47938117

Comment: Hi, try to give **console.log(data.get('image'))**, let me know if it works

Comment: this is what i got:File(4659)
lastModified: 1530958011139
lastModifiedDate: Sat Jul 07 2018 11:06:51 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time) {}
name: "17334146_982301731873467_6292546217318547456_a-1.jpg"
size: 4659
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File

Comment: FormData is not a simple object so it doesn't mean that it's not append. Check what you send to the server in Network DevTools.

Comment: thanks that was quite informative

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileService.uploadPhoto(file.files)">
```

and in your fileService:

```
uploadPhoto(files) {

    if (files.length > 0) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        for (let file of files)
            formData.append(file.name, file);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```