# Read uploaded JSON file in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am using the `<p-fileUpload>` from PrimeNG to upload a json file in my web-app. I want to read the json file, in the front-end, and change some values of a data table.

However, I have no idea how to parse the uploaded file as a json to a typescript object. Any ideas?

In the HTML file:

```
<p-fileUpload #ratingsUpload mode="basic" name="demo[]"
                    url="" accept=".json"
                    styleClass="p-button-raised"
                    [auto]="true" chooseLabel="Upload ratings"
                    (onUpload)="onRatingsUpload($event)"></p-fileUpload>
```

In the typescript file:

```
  onRatingsUpload(event: any) {
    console.log(event.files)
    // TODO:
    // data = JSON(event.files);
  }
```

Edit: I can't get the event to fire. onRatingsUpload does not seem to be called...

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse` to parse JSON.

Comment: [Please follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971238/upload-json-file-using-angular-6) Thanks!

Comment: Guys, the event isn't even firing... I console.log("Hey") inside `onRatingsUpload()` and I never see it..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use FileReader:

```js
 const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (event) => {
  try {
    var obj = JSON.parse((event.target.result) as string);
    console.log('my json:', obj);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
reader.readAsText(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//You need to use FileReader

onFileChanged(event) {
  this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsText(this.selectedFile, "UTF-8");
  fileReader.onload = () => {
   console.log(JSON.parse(fileReader.result));
  }
  fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).