# Get File Path from Input

Tags: angular

I want to display a Highcharts Graph from a chooseable csv File, for this i need it's path.

I have this very simple input which looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file" id="file (change)="function($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

Now, is there any possibility to get the files path from this input?
Are there other ways to let the user choose a file and get its path?

Comment: Looks like you took the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload. Why not follow the rest of the answer?

Comment: I want the path of the uploaded file. I think the other answer is just for uploading a file but doesn't describe how to find out it's path.

Comment: in that answer, `$event.target.files` seems to contain the filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source:

> [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

For security reasons browsers do not allow this, i.e. JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System, however using HTML5 File API, only Firefox provides a mozFullPath property, but if you try to get the value it returns an empty string:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    console.log(this.files[0].mozFullPath);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SCK5A/

So don't waste your time.

edit: If you need the file's path for reading a file you can use the FileReader API instead. Here is a related question on SO: Preview an image before it is uploaded.