# How can i read/write to directory with angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, file-io, angular8, file-browser

I am looking to create a file browser within my angular app and currently can't find anything which will allow me to read/write to a directory within angular 8

This looked promising to be able to populate my directory tree but i get lots of errors around 'fs' and 'path'
https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-tree

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I used `angular2-tree` component for display tree structure in my project.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tree-component

It is impossible to read/write folder structure by angular and script, it is security issue.

I implement API to read folder structure and `angular2-tree` display it.

About upload file to folder, you can make API and use Angular to call API.

You can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/56600381/4964569