# React.js to pain HTML: how to convert imageupload.html react code into angular 6 HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
onChange(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      Storage.put('example.png', file, {
          contentType: 'image/png'
      })
      .then (result => console.log(result))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

imageupload.html

```
<input type="file" accept='image/png' onChange={(evt) => this.onChange(evt)}/>
```

So the following code is in react.How can I write the following code in an angular 6 HTML file? Mainly how to write this`onChange={(evt) => this.onChange(evt)}` part in HTML?

For see the original code: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js#browser-uploads

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload)

Comment: Yes, I get the idea. But how can I write ```onChange={(evt) => this.onChange(evt)}``` this in HTML of my angular

Comment: will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML also have the onchange event attribute you can just call the function in the html like:
`<input type="file" accept='image/png' onchange="onChange(this.value)"/>`

Answer (score 0):

#### To copy+paste ***directly*** from the [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload) I mentioned;

```html
<input 
    type="file"
    id="file"
    (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"
>
```

So all we need to do to get this to work with your code is the following:

```html
<input 
    type="file"
    id="file"
    (change)="onChange($event)" 
>
```

Notice how `(change)` is now slightly different.