# Is the same body sent to the server using forms in Angular?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, express, http-post

I am trying to upload files to the server. I created an Express-App with an index.html and an index.js file.

The index.html file:

```
<h1>File Upload in Node.js App</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The index.js file:

```
app.post('/', (req,res)=>{
    console.log("post file")
    if(req.files){
        console.log(req.files);
        var file = req.files.file
        var filename = file.name;
        console.log(filename);

        file.mv('./uploads/' + filename, function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err)
            } else {
                res.send("File Uploaded")
            }
        })
    }
})
```

It worked very well.
I am trying the post method now within my Angular-App

app.component.html

```
<h1>File Upload in Node.js App</h1>
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" name="file">
<button (click)="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
    fileChange(element) {
      this.files_to_upload = element.target.files;
      console.log(this.files_to_upload);
    }

    uploadFiles(){
        const body = {
            files: this.files_to_upload
        }
        console.log(body);
       this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/",body)
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

The body is different when using the form but why?
In my Express-App `req.files` is not initialized because the function is just console logging `Post file` and stops there.

What is the difference between the two approaches (their bodies) and why does my approach in my Angular-App not work?
What would I have to change? I do not get it.

Comment: i think you should use FormData when sending the file via post in angular, see this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload

Comment: Thank your for sharing the link! I will try it !