# Trying to upload file to server

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to upload file to server but not working and I got this error..

[image]

I don't have any idea how to fix it.. This is my code..

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" #fileUploader (change)="uploadBanner($event.target.files)">
<label class="custom-file-label" #labelImport for="importFile"></label>
<ng-container *ngIf="uploadSuccess">Upload Successful</ng-container>
```

**Component**

```
uploadBanner(files : File){
  let data={
   Id: this.confId,
   file: files[0].name,
   type: "Banner"
  }
  this.httpService.upload(data).subscribe(event =>{
   if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
     this.percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
   } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
     this.uploadSuccess = true;
   }
   
});
}
```

**Service**

```
public upload(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer '+this.getToken()
      })
    };
    var header = {
      
      responseType: 'json',
      reportProgress: true,
    };
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.serverUrl + this.basePath + '/upload',{formData,header,httpOptions});
  }
```

Comment: What's the definition of interface File

Comment: if i not mistaken...The interfaces file is a dictionary of connection information for Adaptive Servers and Open Server applications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload Maybe this can help, do you want to solve TS compiling errors?

Comment: Thanks for link.. Yes.. I want to solve TS compiling error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your upload() accepts a File object, but you are sending a custom object that you created named **data** with 3 attributes in uploadBanner().

To make it work, you can directly pass **files** to the upload() function, or change the type of the upload() parameter to match your object structure.

The following wouldn't be a perfect implementation, but should you give you a rough idea about the issue and expected solution.

```
uploadBanner(files : File){
  let data = {
    Id: this.confId,
    type: "Banner"
  }
  this.httpService.upload(files[0], data).subscribe(event =>{
    ...
  });
}
upload(file, data) {
  ...
  formData.append('file', file, file.name);
  formData.append('Id', data.Id);
  ...
}
```