# How to upload excel file with progress bar in angular without using Jquery?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

How to upload file by adding backend url. I have tried by using simple HTML code. But I need to upload fie with **"progress bar"** or else **"please wait...uploading"**. And I am not able to install jquery, so can anyone help me to do this by using typescript.

**HTML**

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
 
  <label style="font-size: 16px;display:inline;" for="img"><b>Upload File:</b></label>

  <input style="width:250px;margin-left:5%;" value="file" type="file" id="input1" name="img" accept=".xlsx">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload)

Comment: Specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60197231/298455

Comment: In that post , the server url which is the backend url right? @Nishant