# How to pass file from TS Angular to WebApi C#?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, .net-core

I have issue with passing file inside form from Front-End to Backend.
My file on backend side is always null.
Front-End code:

```
public getTranslatedJson(
    json: File,
    destinatonLanguage: Language
  ) {
    const form = {
      "languageCharset": destinatonLanguage.systemId,
      "file": json
    }
    return this.http.post(this.url, form, {responseType: "blob", observe: "response"});
  };
```

Back-End code:

```
 [HttpPost("")]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromForm] LanguageCharset languageCharset, [FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
      var jsonString = new StringBuilder();
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()) // error here because file was null
      {
       [...]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload)

Comment: @Markus No, because it's complete different approach. Mine approach works with a string instead of file, but i really want to use file there and want to achive that.

Comment: IFormFile only works with files submitted via the form input component.