# File Upload button using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am not a native English speaker, so sorry if my English is bad. I am new to Angular and I'm trying to create a file upload button that would allow the user to upload a file according to a dropdown list of options (for example USA States). When the user uploads the file, the file will be saved to a folder in an API. I haven't found a tutorial on the web for something like this. Any idea?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938117/12914833. Official tutorial:  https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/

Comment: Have a look on this, it's really useful and informative.
https://www.ahmedbouchefra.com/angular-tutorial-example-upload-files-with-formdata-httpclient-rxjs-and-material-progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

maybe ican help you using HTML and css

```
<label class="custom-file-upload">
      <input type="file" id="file" (change)="uploadRca($event)"/>Upload
    </label>

input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  place-self: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```