# Laravel multiple file upload using Accessors & Mutators

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an Accessor that sets a file name and path for an uploaded image, and a mutator to retrieve the photo url. It works on single file upload, but i cannot think of a way to convert it for multiple file upload for a user gallery.

this is my input in my blade

```
<input type="file" id="deal_img_input" class="form-control" name="featured_image>
```

this is my model

```
const PATH_PREFIX = 'public/deals';

public function getPhotoNameAttribute()
{
    if ($this->id && $this->featured_photo_extension) {
        return "$this->id.$this->featured_photo_extension";
    }

    return null;
}

public function getPhotoPathAttribute()
{
    if ($name = $this->getPhotoNameAttribute()) {
        return self::PATH_PREFIX . "/$name";
    }

    return null;
}

public function getPhotoUrlAttribute()
{
    $path = $this->getPhotoPathAttribute();
    if (Storage::exists($path)) {
        return Storage::url($path) . '?t=' . Storage::lastModified($path);
    }

    return '/assets/app/store/img/placeholder.jpg';

}

public function setPhotoExtensionAttribute($value)
{
    $path = $this->getPhotoPathAttribute();

    if (Storage::exists($path)) {
        Storage::delete($path);
    }

    $this->attributes['photo_extension'] = $value;
}
```

this is my controller

```
    if ($photo_featured = $request->file('feautured_image')) {
        $deals->featured_photo_alt = 'Featured Photo';
        $deals->featured_photo_extension = $photo_featured->extension();
        $photo_featured->storeAs(Deal::PATH_PREFIX, $deals->photo_name);

    }
    $deals->save();
```

How can i modify the code if i'll have multiple inputs?

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="gallery_image[]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the "multiple" attribute to your input ?

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="gallery_image" multiple="multiple">
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1593259/9291504

Comment: yes, but what happens is only the first input is saved

Comment: php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php should bring an answer, since Laravel extends SplFileInfo. So i guess that 
`$request->file('feautured_image')` 
should return an array