# How to select file and folder with single browser?

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-handling

is it possible to select files or folders with single input tag

Note--->i am able to select mutiple files but problem is for selecting a folder and file we need two buttons. i want to do it by single input field.

```
<input id="input-file" webkitDirectory="" type="file" multiple/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select multiple files with <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593225/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-input-type-file)

Comment: No, i want that user can either select files or folders.

Comment: this answer may help you... https://stackoverflow.com/a/2809706/9085612

Comment: after including webkitDirectory only folder can be selected and in this case we can not select file.

Comment: I think you can not do it with pure HTML. take a look at [this](https://www.examplefiles.net/cs/522988). also, you can use some plugins like dropzone that may help. look at [this](https://www.meziantou.net/upload-files-and-directories-using-an-input-drag-and-drop-or-copy-and-paste-with.htm)