# How can I implement the multiple selection of image file(s) at uploading

Tags: html, css

I want to allow my program to select and upload multiple files at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select multiple files with <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593225/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-input-type-file)

Answer (score 0):

I used multiple inside  tag like this:

```
    <input
                className="btn-browse"
                type="file"
                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png, .gif, .bmp"
                multiple
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can upload multiple files by providing Multiple property in the input tag.

```css
 h1 {
            color: green;
        }
         
        .container {
            text-align: center;
            width: 850px;
            margin: 35px;
        }
         
        .property {
            width: 400px ;
            float: left;
            border: 2px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .attribute {
            width: 400px ;
            float: right;
            border: 2px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="property">
            <form action="/action_page_inputtags_multiplefiles.php">
                <label for="files">Select Multiple files:</label>
                <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```