# How to select multiple files from different directory in html input type="file" element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js, frontend

I want to select multiple files from different directories by using html input type="file" element.
I couldn't find any resource to do this. is there any npm package available that can be used either in react js or vue js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select multiple files with <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593225/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-input-type-file)

Answer (score 1):

on `input` element add `multiple` attribute

```html
 <input
 type="file"
 name="upload-files"
 multiple
/>
```

If on chrome. firefox and and to upload folder.

```
  <input
     type="file"
     name="upload-files"
     multiple
     directory={isDirectorySelectable ? "directory" : null}
     webkitdirectory={isDirectorySelectable ? "webkitdirectory" : null}
   />
```

Comment: This is for selecting the folder, but is there any option to select just the files from different directory.

Comment: You can only select files / folders from the current open file dialog. So you couldn't multiple files from multiple directory because you can only select file/ folder at a time