# I am trying to implement multiple file upload in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to upload multiple images in React as array. It is uploading the images but suppose I select 2 images it uploads only one image and gives other image is undefined.
Here's the code:

```
 const [labImages, setLabImages] = useState([])

  const handleLabImagesUpload = (e) => {
    setLabImages([...labImages, e.target.files[0]])
  }

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
 console.log(labImages)
}

//JSX Part
<label className="text-base xs:text-xl w-[180px] xs:w-[210px] text-white border-[1px] font-bold border-black px-4 py-[2px] rounded">
              <input
                type="file"
                className="cursor-pointer"
                onClick={handleLabImagesUpload}
              />
              Upload Lab Images
</label>

<button
            className="bg-secondary text-white font-bold text-xl px-8 rounded py-1 lg:px-12"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
 > Submit </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1593259/10509081), the input element can accept multiple files if given the `multiple` attribute.

**Edit:**

`onClick` on the input will execute as soon as the input element is clicked, not when you select the files. At that point in time, `e.target.files[0]` will be undefined.

To access the files after a value has been selected, try the `onChange` event instead.

Also, why manually append the first file? If `e.target.files` is an array, you could just use the array directly.

Comment: It is selecting multiple file but on submitting when that `handleSubmit` runs, it logs  "undefined" in the console

Comment: what is `handleLabImagesUpload` doing? Where are you actually setting the `labImages` state? You initialize it with an empty array but I never see it getting updated.

Comment: ohh so sorry.  I have updated the code, I missed to put that part of the code