# Can't upload multiple files PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, file

I have a problem. I want to be able to upload one or more files from html and then with ajax and php to save them on my server. If i just want to upload one file, it works fine, but if I want to upload more than one it doesn't work. The thing is, i have a table with 4 options and the last one is upload. But there is an ADD button under that, so when I click on that button another table (the same table) apperas, and there is where I have the problem.
This is the HTML code part:

```
   <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
              <tbody id="personalInfo">
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name0"
                      placeholder="<?php echo  $translate['name'][$lang]?>">
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname0"
                    placeholder="<?php echo  $translate['surname'][$lang]?>">
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datepickerYear" name="age0" autocomplete="off"
                    placeholder="2000" required />
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="pt-1">
                      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="UploadFile" name="UploadFile0" accept="application/pdf" required />
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  
                  <td class="col-sm-1"><a class="deleteRow"></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger " id="addRow"
                      value="<?php echo  $translate['add'][$lang]?>" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Okey and then I use JS to add another row when I click the ADD button. Everything works fine, but with the file I do this:

```
 var fileCounter = 0;  

      const fileSelector2 = document.getElementById('UploadFile');
      var file2;
      
      fileSelector2.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        
        file2 = event.target.files[fileCounter];
        fileCounter++;
      });
```

And then with JS i use ajax to send it a POST to php.
The php part is this:

```
$name=$json->fullName ;

            $location = "../location/" .$name.$cont. ".pdf"; 

                        
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'], $location)) {
                echo json_encode(-1);
                exit();
            }
```

Like I said, when I just upload one file, it works fine, but with more than one file I don't know how to save t and use POST with multiple files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select multiple files with <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593225/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-input-type-file)

Comment: @DarkBee, no because in my case i don't want to upload multiple files on one <intput>, i have multiple <input> with multiple files (not always the same amount), so I want to save them on one variable (like an array) and then upload them one by one.

Comment: `i have multiple <input> with multiple files` - According to the code you've posted you do not. Please provide all the essential code and information